# user.setRole is not a function using sequlize postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am facing an issue in the association of sequelize

My data was saved in the database but roles are not saved

I making registration using postgres but facing an issue of setRole is not defined

My code is

Auth_User.js is a model for signIn and signUp user we create the association in this file

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";
import { sequelize } from "../Database/database";

 const Auth_User = sequelize.define("authUsers", {
  userName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
 });

Auth_User.associate = function(models) {
  Auth_User.belongsToMany(models.Role, { through: 'user_roles', foreignKey: 'userId', otherKey: 'roleId'});
 
};

export default Auth_User;
```

Role.js in this file we create a role model where we have admin and user

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";
import { sequelize } from "../Database/database";

const Role = sequelize.define('roles', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
  });
Role.associate = function(models) {
Role.belongsToMany(models.Auth_User, { through: 'user_roles', foreignKey: 'roleId', otherKey: 'userId'})
};

export default Role;
```

Know signup.js
here we create signup we are facing the issue in this file
making issue here user.setRole is not a function

```
import Auth_User from '../Model/auth.model';
import Role from '../Model/role.model';
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var db= require('../Database/database')
const Op = db.Sequelize.Op;

 
export const signup = (req, res) => {
  // Save Auth_User to Database
  console.log("Processing func -> SignUp");
  
  Auth_User.create({
    userName: req.body.userName,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 8)
  }).then(user => {
    Role.findAll({
      where: {
      name: {
        [Op.or]: req.body.roles.map(role => role.toUpperCase())
      }
      }
    }).then(roles => {
      console.log(user)
      user.setRole(roles).then(() => {
        res.send("User registered successfully!");
         
            });
    }).catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send("Error -> " + err);
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send("Fail! Error -> " + err);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I recommend you to be really careful with the `model name` you choose in the model definition: `sequelize.define(modelName, attributes, options)`. Sequelize automatically makes the plural for you, so a good way to define tables is to always use the singular, but of course this is completely optional. This means that if you use as model name `role` instead of `roles`, the table name will be automatically set as `roles` by Sequelize.

The second recommendation is to not use the uppercase in this same model name, because when you have to deal with automatically created foreign keys and you want to access them through `object.property`, you will have to use upper or lowercase depending on how you defined the name. So, for example if you have a `companyId` in a `Users` table, in order to obtain it you will have to call `user.CompanyId` if your model name for the *company table* was written as `Company` and `user.companyId` if it was written as `company`.

Finally, and answering your main question, I recommend you to look the official docs for Sequelize regarding the **Special methods/mixins added to instances** (https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#special-methods-mixins-added-to-instances), where you will find all the different combinations depending on the association. In your specific case, for a `belongsToMany` association, its special method has to be used using the plural form. In your case, it should be `user.setRoles(roles)`. This doesn't apply, however, if you prefer to use the `add method`, which can be used either as `user.addRole(roles)` or `user.addRoles(roles)`